# Add Action Bar without Subclassing ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

Is it possible to add an Action Bar to an android application:
1) without subclassing ActionBarActivity
2) support for gingerbread and newer

I've searched google and SO, no results.

The reason I ask this is because I have an activity that already subclasses from another library, and I can't make the ActionBarActivity the root subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally no, multiple inheritance isn't part of Java.

Of course, the real question is if `ActionBarActivity` will actually be useful on Gingerbread. It depends on what specific functionality you need from it.

What you can *try* to do:

- Make your own "ActionBar" via layout.
- If the library you're using is open source, modify it so its Activities extend `ActionBarActivity` instead.
- If not, both ActionBarCompat is [open source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master/v7/appcompat) - you can download the source and incorporate the functionality into your Activity. `ActionBarActivity` does extend `FragmentActivity`, so you may need to work with the raw support-library [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java) as well.

Comment: Thats current what i'm doing(using my own action-like bar), but its a not as nice looking,, and I'm interested in some of the things that come for free with the Action Bar.  I'll def try these

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer for Q2 is YES. You use support library v7 to support Action Bars on devices running GingerBread (Eclairs and Froyos as well).

For Q1, i believe the answer is an YES. You just use the `Window.requestFeature()` to add Action Bars. But i am not very sure about this.

HTH.